# How to generate simulation paths for Weibull distribution in R?

Tags: r, survival, simulation, hazard

I'm trying to generate simulation paths across time in R for survival and hazard functions using the Weibull distribution. Here are the steps I'm taking so far. I need direction because I'm not able to generate simulation paths with the below:

**First:** Here's an example of a single basic hazard curve generated in R which works fine (code followed by image):

```
# function for hazard:
weibHaz <- function(x, shape, scale) dweibull(x, shape=shape,
              scale=scale)/pweibull(x, shape=shape, scale=scale,lower.tail=F)

# plot hazard:
curve(weibHaz(x, shape=1.5, scale=1/0.03), from=0, to=80, ylab='Hazard', xlab='Time', col='red')
```

[image]

**Second:** Generate random numbers from Weibull distribution and store them in `simulated_data`, using same parameters as in the above hazard curve:

```
set.seed(123) # set a seed for reproducibility
simulated_data <- rweibull(n = 20, shape=1.5, scale=1/0.03)
```

**Third:** plot the simulation results (code followed by image):

```
# ts() creates a time series object from the simulated data
# frequency = 1 indicates the time series data is not periodic
ts_data <- ts(simulated_data, start = 1, frequency = 1)
plot(ts_data, main = "Simulated Time Series Data", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Data")
```

[image]

The third step above obviously shows incorrect results. I need to see 20 curves over 80 time periods. The below image shows the type of simulation paths I've generated before using other data and using autoregressive time-series models. This is the form of output data and plot I'm looking for for the hazard curve generated with the Weibull distribution. Any recommendations for doing this correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `simulated_data` are just 20 draws from a single fixed Weibull distribution having the specified `shape` and `scale` values. They are just samples of individual survival times drawn from that single distribution. This shows the associated survival function:

```
 plot(1:70,1-pweibull(1:70,shape=1.5, scale=1/0.03),type="l",bty="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Survival probability")
```

If the Weibull distribution is fixed, then the survival function is also fixed and there would be no variability in survival curves.

If you want to evaluate uncertainty in survival-curve estimates based on modeled data, then you want to draw from distributions of the `shape` and `scale` values consistent with the variance-covariance matrix of their modeled estimates, for example with the `mvrnorm()` function of the R [`MASS` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MASS), and display the set of survival curves in the way indicated above.

Comment: I know comments aren't to be used for "thank you", but you are quite the educator and supportive so anyhow THANK YOU. Now I can adjust my path.